# Do custom dashed lines fail when rotated?

Tags: qgis, symbology

Discontinuous lines work fine when they are at right angles (0°, 90°) but as they are drawn at a greater or lesser angle, their defined spacing expands, i.e. they do not maintain the distances I defined at the beginning.
The subject is the representation of an electric or telephone power line, for the case only one marker changes.
I defined 3 layers, the base layer is the discontinuous one with 6 mm in black and 4 mm of empty space. On top I put a dot marker that goes in the middle of the black line and repeats in each one (every 10 mm). The third layer is an SVG marker emulating the letters "EL" (Electric) shown in the space. Likewise, they are repeated every 10 mm.

[image]

You can see in the image that it works fine straight on, but as the angle changes, the markers stay in place, but the line moves.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QGIS seems to calculate the spacing of angled dashed lines incorrectly. My QGIS version 3.16 does it too.

A workaround: instead of the dashed simple line, use a third marker line.
As its simple marker use a vertical line (|) and rotate it 90°.

For me that seems to work in all orientations.